# How to reload Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

Here is my situation :

I'm retrieving data from a database in a fragment and the result is asynchronous. So I want to reload the view after I get result from database.

I've tried many ways with "Fragment Transaction" like this one :

```
private void reloadView(ViewGroup container){
    Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(container.getId());
    if (currentFragment instanceof StatsFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = (getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.commit();}

}
```

Do you think there is a better way to do it ? Can I put an adapter or something like that ? (I wanted to do it but all the tutorial I have found talks about adapter for listview in fragment).

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) out.
Replace your `ListView` with `RecycleView`.

Comment: Do it in your Fragment, with a fonction `updateView()` where you all it in `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I would suggest you to just update adapter instead of doing a heavy job. It doesn't matter ListView or RecycleView just update new data to the list and use `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do this:

1. Keep track of what you want to update, and then update the single components (TextViews, ListViews, etc)
2. Take a look at [**Android data binding library**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

I personally use data binding everywhere is possible because it's simply amazing.